# Problems with internet connection under ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am newbie ubuntu user (just migrated from windows) .

And i am trying to connect to internet and having problems with that .

I connect via that [modem](http://broadband.motorola.com/consumers/products/sb4200/) , but i cant see how I establish the connection under ubuntu.

Tried googling that, but can't see relevant information .

Thanks , a lot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the cable modem pushes out a DHCP address, Ubuntu should pick up everything by default.  `ifconfig` should show you what ethernet devices are on the system.

Try `ifconfig -a` and report back what it provides as output.

You'll also want to check `/etc/network/interfaces`.  It should look something like this if you're using DHCP:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

just to start with, I would suggest you to take a look at the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/).

If you'll find other problems, you could write some more informations about your issue:

- release of Ubuntu
- what do you want to achieve
- what do you do in order to achieve it
- what happens

for instance. Any further information (could) be helpful.

Hope to hear from you soon, though!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the NetworkManager icon and click Edit connections
2. Click DSL
3. Click Add

https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/internet/C/connecting-dsl.html